# Unable to get property 'new_textholder' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, null, undefined-reference, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm using code I found online to convert a standard option set field to a checkbox in MS CRM 2015 online. It keeps giving me the above error.

Here is the code:

```
function MultiPickList3(param1, param2, param3,param4,param5) 
{ 
try 
{ 
var fn = arguments.callee.toString().match(/function\s+([^\s\(]+)/);  

if (param1==null || param2==null) 
{ 
alert("Error: Parameter missing. \n Format: <optionset fieldname> ,  <option value text field> ,  [<option header>], [<select color>]   ,   [<deselect color>] ,  \n ["+"Function="+fn[1]+"]"  ); 
return true; 
} 

var tparamtype=Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(param1).getAttributeType(); 
if (tparamtype!="optionset") 
  { alert (param1+"(first parameter) should be of type optionset \n"+"[function="+fn[1]+"]"); 
    return true; 
  } 

var tparamtype=Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(param2).getAttributeType(); 
if (tparamtype!="memo") 
  { alert (param2+"(second parameter) should be of type memo (text with mutiline) \n[function="+fn[1]+"]"); 
    return true; 
  } 

var plOptions=param1;       
var plText=param2;     
var plMenuItem="View Selected List"; 
var SelectedList_orig = crmForm.all[plText]; 
var FullList=crmForm.all[plOptions]; 

var SelCtr=-1; 
var new_selColor="orange"; 
var new_deSelColor="white"; 
if (param4!=null) 
    new_selColor=param4; 
if (param5!=null) 
    new_deSelColor=param5; 

var SelectedList =SelectedList_orig.value.split("\r\n"); 
crmForm.all[plText].style.display="none"; 

if(FullList!=null && SelectedList!=null) 
    { 
     initColor(); 
     if (param3!=null && param3!="") 
        { 
             plMenuItem=param3; 
        } 
   else 
       {  
          plMenuItem=FullList.options[0].text; 
           changeColor("grey",0); 
       } 

     for (var ctr=0; ctr<SelectedList.length;ctr++) 
         { 
           selCtr=SelectedIndex(SelectedList[ctr]); 
             if (selCtr >-1) 
               {        
                   changeColor(new_selColor,selCtr); 
                } 
         } 
     } 

function SelectedIndex(selectedText) 
{ 
var FullListText; 
for (var ctr1=0; ctr1<FullList.options.length;ctr1++) 
    { 
      FullListText=FullList.options[ctr1].text; 
      if ( FullListText==selectedText) 
         { 
            return ctr1; 
         } 
     } 
return -2; 
} 

crmForm.all[plOptions].attachEvent('onchange', OnChangePL); 

function OnChangePL()  
{ 
var SelCtr=-1; 
var sel=crmForm.all[plOptions].SelectedText; 

if (sel==plMenuItem) 
return; 

SelCtr=SelectedIndex(sel); 
var SelColor="grey";  
SelColor=crmForm.all[plOptions][SelCtr].style.backgroundColor; 

if (SelColor==new_selColor) 
     { 
       changeColor(new_deSelColor,SelCtr); 
       saveChanges(sel,selCtr,"del"); 
    } 
else 
    { 
       changeColor(new_selColor, SelCtr);              
       saveChanges(sel,selCtr,"add"); 
    } 
} 

function saveChanges(p_selText,p_SelCtr,p_mode) 
{ 
switch(p_mode) 
{ 
    case "add": 
            SelectedList.push(p_selText); 
            break; 
    case "del": 
            for (var ctr2=0;ctr2<SelectedList.length;ctr2++) 
                 { 
                  if (SelectedList[ctr2]==p_selText) 
                       { 
                         SelectedList.splice(ctr2,1); 
                         break; 
                       }  
                  } 
              break; 
} 
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(plText).setValue(SelectedList.join("\r\n"));   
} 

function initColor() 
{ 
      for (var ctr3=0; ctr3<FullList.options.length;ctr3++) 
           {             changeColor(new_deSelColor, ctr3);   } 
} 

function changeColor(newColor, newCtr) 
{ 
      crmForm.all[plOptions][newCtr].style.backgroundColor=newColor; 
} 

} 
catch (e) 
         {  alert (e.description);} 
}
```

param2 takes the field "new_textholder" which is a multiline text field. It's defined on the form and I have checked to make sure I am writing it correctly.

What could be the problem?

Thank you!!

Comment: Where is new_textholder in that code?

Comment: it isn't. In defining the event handler OnLoad I defined the parameters being used from the field. param2 (in the list of parameters for the function MultiPickList3) takes "new_textholder".

Comment: The code is messing with the DOM, which is unsupported and likely to break when new versions or rollup updates of Dynamics CRM are released. My advice is to put no effort in this. Instead you're beter off designing an HTML web resource and embed it in your form.

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely coming from the crmForm.all[plText] line.  I'm guessing your org is recent enough that support for the old 4.0 api is no longer present, which would mean that the `all` object is no longer available, which would give you that error (plText is set to the value of param2).  You might be able to modify this code to work on your 2015 form, but I don't have a 2015 org available to me at the moment so I can't say for sure.

Comment: How would I go about fixing the issue?

Comment: It'd difficult to say without having a 2015 form available.  You could start by  checking out some of these links: https://www.google.com/search?q=upgrade+crm+4.0+javascript+to+2011